# How can I extract only the link out of an <a href, which includes li elements, using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am all new to python and beautifulsoup. I want to get the link form the href. Unfortunately, the anchor also includes other and irrelevant data.

Help is much apreciated

```html
<a href="/link-i-want/to-get.html">
<li class="cat-list-row1 clearfix">
<img align="left" alt="Do not need!" src="https://do.not/need/.jpg" style="margin-right: 20px;" width="40%"/>
<h3>
<p class="subline">Do not need</p> Do not need!    </h3>
<span class="tag-body">
<p>Do not need</p>...    </span>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</li>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Attribute value can be extracted using `[]` brackets.

For instance, if to extract `alt` value an `img` tag use:
`image_example = soup.find('img')` and then `print(image_example['alt'])`

Updated code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
    <a href="/link-i-want/to-get.html">
    <li class="cat-list-row1 clearfix">
    <img align="left" alt="Do not need!" src="https://do.not/need/.jpg" style="margin-right: 20px;" width="40%"/>
    <h3>
    <p class="subline">Do not need</p>  Do not need!                </h3>
    <span class="tag-body">
    <p>Do not need</p>...               </span>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </li>
    </a>    <a href="/link-i-want/to-get.html">
    <li class="cat-list-row1 clearfix">
    <img align="left" alt="Do not need!" src="https://do.not/need/.jpg" style="margin-right: 20px;" width="40%"/>
    <h3>
    <p class="subline">Do not need</p>  Do not need!                </h3>
    <span class="tag-body">
    <p>Do not need</p>...               </span>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </li>
    </a>
'''    
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
url_address = soup.find('a')['href']
print (url_address) # Output: /link-i-want/to-get.html
```

The format is as follows.
`soup.find('<tag>')['<attribute-name>']` .

We can use `.get(attr)` like mentioned. `soup.find('<tag>').get('<attr>')`

Reference: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start

Comment: Thanks a lot ! However your way didn´t work out for me. I got it working with -> link.get('href')

Comment: @TheTresckow, actually if `link.get('href')` is getting you the value, `link['href']` will give the same (maybe you are doing something wrong in implementation?). The only difference between these two methods is `.get(attr)` returns `None` if the attribute is not present and the other raises a `KeyError`.